# How to scan for bluetooth LE devices via dbus API?

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

I'm trying to scan for bluetooth LE devices using the bluez DBus API. I've installed bluez-5.25 using

```
--enable-experimental
```

configure option. I can see in the build that support has been compiled in.
Interfaces like HeartBeat, ThermoMeter etc. appear in DBus but not the

```
org.bluez.ProximityMonitor1
```

interface. As far as I understand it this interface would be needed for permanent scan for bluetooth LE devices with information about the distance. But I just started to deal with bluez so I'm not sure.

Are all of the necessary things available in the DBus API? And what is needed in order to scan permanently for LE devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register for DBUS creations of org.bluez.Device1 proxy objects. The org.bluez.Adapter1 interface can then be used to StartDiscovery. This will scan for both Classic and LE devices. When a device is detected a Device1 object will be created and your registered callback will be invoked.

Comment: I'm doing it that way now. It seems I need to actively scan to see the devices. Passive scanning does not emit dbus messages. I'm trying to track LE devices. The InterfacesAdded is only emitted at first discovery. What would be the way to implement if I want to know if a device is still near me? I thought the proximity can be used for that but it is not there. Don't know if bluez is not working or the device does not support the profile.

Comment: The Proximity Monitor profile is not the same as scanning. You need to have scanned before you can even use that profile (or any profile). Scanning = discovering nearby devices (to get its BT address and services). Proximity Monitor = after discovery, use that service, if supported by the remote device, to read rssi values and optionally alert based on proximity.

Comment: I wasn't very clear. I scanned for devices and then examined each that has been found. I would have expected to find a device that offers the ProximityMonitor Interface. But I saw that nowhere. I have bluez compiled with --enable-experimental and I started the daemon with -E. But then I'm not sure if I can see the interface only if it announces the interdface and my beacons do not support it.